# Is it possible to detect which Activity holds a View

Tags: android

I have a `View` and I need to get an `Activity` which holds a `layout` where this `View` reside. I know there is a `getContext()` method for the `View` to get a `Context`, but is there a way to get an `Activity`? Thanks.

Comment: I am just guessing if setTag and getTag on the view will be useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call getContext on your view and cast it into an Activity object

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I was just thinking it is another `Context`, thanks!